# Telerik Reporting REST API not accepting cross origin requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api, telerik-reporting

My API has a `ReportsController` set up like so:

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services;
using Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
    {
        static ReportServiceConfiguration configurationInstance;

        static ReportsController()
        {
            configurationInstance = new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                HostAppId = "Html5App",
                Storage = new FileStorage(),
                ReportResolver = new ReportTypeResolver(),
                // ReportSharingTimeout = 0,
                // ClientSessionTimeout = 15,
            };
        }

        public ReportsController()
        {
            //Initialize the service configuration
            this.ReportServiceConfiguration = configurationInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

My `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        config.EnableCors();
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

My `web.config` has the recommended binding redirects:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

As far as I can tell, everything is set up correctly, I can call `api/reports/formats` and see the correct data.  When I try to load this report, I get an error.

```
$("#reportViewer1").telerik_ReportViewer({
    serviceUrl: "http://dev-api/api/reports",
    reportSource: {
        report: "Logic.Reports.Report1, Logic",
        parameters: reportParam
    },
});
```

It displays:
"Error loading the report viewer's templates. (Template = http://dev-api/api/reports/resources/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-html)."

on the page, and displays

`Failed to load http://dev-api/api/reports/resources/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-html: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64634' is therefore not allowed access.`

in the Chrome console.  I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Allow CORS in your WEB API See this doc :[Enable CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

- Manage NuGet Package by installing Microsoft ASP.NET CORs
- Add Following lines of code in web.Config under System.WebSe
- Add Following Lines of code in your web.config in system.WebServer section

.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Add [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] in your Controller